# admob smart banner needs to be on bottom of app (via java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, banner

I have my smart banner working, but I'd like it to appear at the bottom of my app instead of at the top where it currently is--preferably with java.

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AdView adView;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "unique_id_here";

private ImageView mPlayPic;

MediaPlayer mRainSound;

private ImageView mBgImg;

private ImageView mNextPicButton;

private int currentImage = 0;

int[] images = { R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.rsz_1pic9, R.drawable.rsz_pic7 };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_rain);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("0C179D00E6B9B79C492DCCA6A64B1FA9") //gotten from running as Debug and reading logcat
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/pic4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picImage"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/opaq_mountain" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playImage"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/square_play_opac" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` for your ad:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) adView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
adView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Add this code after `layout.addView(adView);`

Comment: Means a lot that you took the time to answer my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

And another linear layout at the end inside your relative layout. Set android: layout_gravity to bottom for this linear layout and add your adview to this linear layout. Worked for me.

Comment: This will not work unless you align the linear layout to the bottom of the relative layout. If you are doing that, why not just align the ad itself to the bottom? An alternative is to place the relative layout inside a vertical linear layout, and then also add the adView to it after the relative layout. If the relative layout's height is match_parent and the ad's is wrap_content, it will align correctly at the bottom.